# Replace a specific word in a text file

Tags: c, csv, text-files, strtok, fseek

Hello one of the exercise I have to do is to create a function that you put three parameters the row the col and a word. In fact, I have to work with a csv file of 3 cols so when the user inserts three parameters I have to replace in the specific row and col the word by the word that he puts. I success to do the first to things to find the rows and the cols and also the word that I have to replace but I don't success to replace this word in the csv file I don't know how I can do this (perhaps with fseek ?). So I need your help in order to solve my problem that I don't solve since many days. 
Thanks You, I trust in your help !

```
int changeValue(int rows, int cols, char *curr_line, char* string_to_replace, char *original_file) 
{
    int count_line = 0, flag_rows = 0, i = 0;
    char line_to_split[100]; char *split = NULL; char *arr[3];

    while (fgets(curr_line, SIZE, original_file) != NULL)
    {
        count_line++;
        if (count_line == rows)
        {
            flag_rows = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag_rows)
    {
        strcpy(line_to_split, curr_line);
        printf("Line to split is : %s\n", line_to_split);
        split = strtok(line_to_split, ",");
        while (split != NULL)
        {
            arr[i] = split;
            printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
            i++;
            split = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        printf("Le numero correspondant a votre ligne est : %s\n", arr[cols - 1]);
        arr[cols - 1] = string_to_replace;  // I want to do this update in the text file
        printf("Bye\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `char *original_file` --> `FILE *original_file`

Comment: Replacement of a string of the same size can by `fseek`.
However, if not so, you need read to in all the memory or you need a separate working file.